# Removing all punctuation marks in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-mining, text-analysis

I need to remove all punctuation marks in the string, as a part of bigger program. 
It is working when I write it serepatly for each mark like this:

```
words = [word.replace(".", "") for word in words]
```

But when I am trying to do it in the loop, it is not working.

```
line = "I was going to leave her, but in the very last moment I had changed 
my mind. Interesting thing, many nice ways to use."
words = line.lower().split()
for punc in [".",","]:
    if punc in words:
        words = [word.replace(punc, "") for word in words]
print words
```

Can you please tell me, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: There is no reason to split your string into words for this, remove the punctuation first and then split if you need to (see the dupes)

Comment: @Chris_Rands thanks, I just need it for further code, was not realizing, that it is causing a trouble. Now it is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`translate` will work for you:

```
>>line = '''I was going to leave her, but in the very last moment I had changed 
my mind. Interesting thing, many nice ways to use.'''
>>line = line.translate(None, ',.')
I was going to leave her but in the very last moment I had changed 
my mind Interesting thing many nice ways to use
```

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Your Problem is

```
if punc in words:
```

This checks if one element of the list is `punc`, not if any of the elements in the list contains `punc`. Just get rid of that line and it should work.